# Django 2 multi model update view

Tags: python, django, model

I'm having a really hard time trying to get an update view class to work.

I'm trying to make a cooking recipe app. I found an example of a createview that handles multiple models. im trying to write an update view, but. When ive plugged in my url, the page renders blank with no records.

I think the problem is withthe context data, but my experiance with djagno is very limited.

my class is below

```
class RecipeUpdateView(UpdateView):

model = Recipe
form_class = RecipeForm
success_url = '/recipe/'

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    self.object = None
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    ingredient_form = IngredientFormSet()
    instruction_form = InstructionFormSet()
    return self.render_to_response(
        self.get_context_data(form=form,
                              ingredient_form=ingredient_form,
                              instruction_form=instruction_form))

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    self.object = None
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    ingredient_form = IngredientFormSet(self.request.POST)
    instruction_form = InstructionFormSet(self.request.POST)
    if (form.is_valid() and ingredient_form.is_valid() and
            instruction_form.is_valid()):
        return self.form_valid(form, ingredient_form, instruction_form)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form, ingredient_form, instruction_form)

def form_valid(self, form, ingredient_form, instruction_form):

    self.object = form.save()
    ingredient_form.instance = self.object
    ingredient_form.save()

    instruction_form.instance = self.object
    instruction_form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

def form_invalid(self, form, ingredient_form, instruction_form):

    return self.render_to_response(
        self.get_context_data(form=form,
                              ingredient_form=ingredient_form,
                              instruction_form=instruction_form))
```

I deleted the get function and replaced it with the below code:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    form = super(RecipeUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if self.request.POST:
        form['ingredient_form'] = IngredientFormSet(
            self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
        form['instruction_form'] = InstructionFormSet(
            self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
    else:
        form['ingredient_form'] = IngredientFormSet(instance=self.object)
        form['instruction_form'] = InstructionFormSet(instance=self.object)
    return form
```

the  form now returns back but, it doesnt save or make it back to the succes url, it does render the extra additions to the form, it looks like the is_valid in the post function is failing but I have no idea why.

can any one help with this?

Ben

Comment: I ended up solving by using:

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by using the following

```
from django.db import transaction



class RecipeUpdateView(UpdateView):

model = Recipe
form_class = RecipeForm
success_url = '/recipe/'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    form = super(RecipeUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if self.request.POST:
        form['ingredient_form'] = IngredientFormSet(
            self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
        form['instruction_form'] = InstructionFormSet(
            self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
    else:
        form['ingredient_form'] = IngredientFormSet(instance=self.object)
        form['instruction_form'] = InstructionFormSet(instance=self.object)
    return form

def form_valid(self, form):
    print("am I valid tho")
    context = self.get_context_data()
    ingredient_form = context['ingredient_form']
    instruction_form = context['instruction_form']
    with transaction.atomic():
        self.object = form.save()

        if ingredient_form.is_valid():
            ingredient_form.instance = self.object
            ingredient_form.save()

        if instruction_form.is_valid():
            instruction_form.instance = self.object
            instruction_form.save()

    return super(RecipeUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)

def form_invalid(self, form, ingredient_form, instruction_form):

    return self.render_to_response(
        self.get_context_data(form=form,
                              ingredient_form=ingredient_form,
                              instruction_form=instruction_form))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ben. It would be better if you could add your model classes, templates, and forms realization into your question.

But here I'm posting info below that may help you as well at the point.

Guess you're using Django Rest Framework and it seems you're trying to update multiple ingredients and instructions same time. I'd recommend starting with refactoring.

Where [] - this a field.

```
RecipeModel:
    [description]
    [ingredients  [Unit name] [Unit amount] [Unit value(pcs, oz, litres)]]
    [instructions [Text]]
```

Here we see that `Ingredients` may be reusable in many recipes, so it's nice to implement it as a `ForeignKey` in `Recipe`. But that statement is not the same for `Instructions` which consist of text paragraphs only and it's unique for almost every new recipe. The only thing I suppose that instructions may have is steps. So I would recommend setting `Instructions` as `CharField`.

After refactoring you'll get only one RecipeModel instance and be able to create a **ModelForm** which is suits a lot better to your case rather than multiple formsets. Check it out: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/

However, if you really want to see current implementation working. Try to set prefixes to each formset:

> Each formset’s prefix replaces the default form prefix that’s added to each field’s name and id HTML attributes.

```
from django.forms import formset_factory
from django.shortcuts import render
from myapp.forms import ArticleForm, BookForm

def manage_articles(request):
    ArticleFormSet = formset_factory(ArticleForm)
    BookFormSet = formset_factory(BookForm)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        article_formset = ArticleFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='articles') # <---
        book_formset = BookFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='books') #<---
        if article_formset.is_valid() and book_formset.is_valid():
            # do something with the cleaned_data on the formsets.
            pass
    else:
        article_formset = ArticleFormSet(prefix='articles') # <---
        book_formset = BookFormSet(prefix='books') # <---
    return render(request, 'manage_articles.html', {
        'article_formset': article_formset,
        'book_formset': book_formset,
    })
```

Source: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/#using-more-than-one-formset-in-a-view